# how to convert xml into programmatic in android

Tags: android, xml

> i have av xml file using relativelayout thats works fine , now i want it to convert as programmatic form, my xml is..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/b"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/a"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="" />    

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/d"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b"/>

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/c"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_below="@+id/b"/>    

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/a"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/d"
    android:layout_below="@+id/d"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/e"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_below="@+id/c"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/f"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/e"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/e"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/a"
    android:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> pls give me idea how to convert it as programmatic.. i tried to convert to write in programmatic form but i dont know addrule.. guide me..

Comment: What do you mean by "convert to programmatic form"? Do you want to add views dynamically at runtime? Can you specify the reason? There might be other options

Comment: No automatic tool that convert XML to JAVA code in my knowledge if you got than please inform me thanks

Comment: @leo: programmatic form means i want this code as java format..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout =  new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    TextView textViewB = new TextView(this);
    textViewB.setId(1);
    textViewB.setText("b");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsB = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParamsB.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    layoutParamsB.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    textViewB.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsB);


    TextView textViewD = new TextView(this);
    textViewD.setId(2);
    textViewD.setText("d");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsD = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParamsB.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    layoutParamsD.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,textViewB.getId());
    textViewD.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsD);


    TextView textViewC = new TextView(this);
    textViewC.setId(3);
    textViewC.setText("c");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsC = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParamsC.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,textViewB.getId());
    layoutParamsC.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT);
    textViewC.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsC);


    TextView textViewA = new TextView(this);
    textViewA.setId(4);
    textViewA.setText("a");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsA = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParamsA.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,textViewD.getId());
    layoutParamsA.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,textViewC.getId());
    textViewA.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsA);


    TextView textViewE = new TextView(this);
    textViewE.setId(5);
    textViewE.setText("e");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsE = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParamsE.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,textViewC.getId());
    layoutParamsE.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT);
    textViewE.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsE);


    TextView textViewF = new TextView(this);
    textViewF.setId(6);
    textViewF.setText("f");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsF = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParamsF.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,textViewA.getId());
    layoutParamsF.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,textViewE.getId());
    textViewF.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsF);

    relativeLayout.addView(textViewB);
    relativeLayout.addView(textViewD);
    relativeLayout.addView(textViewC);
    relativeLayout.addView(textViewA);
    relativeLayout.addView(textViewE);
    relativeLayout.addView(textViewF);

    setContentView(relativeLayout);
}
```

Comment: Wow....what a spoon feeding! Keep it up.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the following code to add rule:

```
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    parentView.addView(linearLayout, layoutParams);
```

Comment: i need the complete code for above xml

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you should not (and you are not allowed to) ask about any tools or resources.

But still, I know one tool which you could use to generate Java code for your XML layout, which is [Android Layout Finder](https://www.buzzingandroid.com/tools/android-layout-finder/). In this web tool, you just need to paste XML, select appropriate options and it will give you Java code.

Comment: I think @Paresh his just want generate same layout using java code or run time.

Comment: @Haresh his question is unclear, but I posted this answer based on the comments regarding tool. I thought he might be looking for a tool! BTW, thanks for the down vote!

Comment: Hello brother i haven't down vote your ans please this down vote done by some other not me i just want clarify question with you and i don't think you gave any wrong direction

Comment: @PareshMayani I did downvote your answer, but simply because he never mentioned anything about a tool, at least not clearly. The comment about a tool is very random from someone else, not the OP. Don't take it personal, I'm pretty sure you have a lot nice answers I'd be happy to up vote. Cheers mate

Comment: @Leo yeah cheers. Question wasn't clear and I saw comment regarding tool so I tried to suggest this layout finder tool. Actually, I have written series of articles on being a lazy and a productive android developer so I know about such tools :) Anyway, it's OK, it happens sometime. This answer would be helpful to others!

Comment: @all: i was not asked any tool to convert xml to java code. I just asked idea/Tricks to write xml code as java code perfectly. because i feel very difficult to write xml code into java code....